# MySql Tally system with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to condense data that I have in my database into rows with their points tallied to see the most popular.

If I had a data table like:

```
   `data`
item1  item2
  1     
  1     2
  1     3
  1     3
  2     3
```

And wanted the condensed version to be:

```
     `data_sum`
item1  item2  Tally
  1      2      2
  1      3      3
  2      3      1
```

How would I achieve this? I have somewhat of an idea here:

```
$popdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data");
    while($add = @mysql_fetch_array($popdata)){         
        $qitem1 = "SELECT * FROM data_sum WHERE item1='".$add['item1']."'";
        $ritem1 = mysql_query($qitem1);
        if(mysql_num_rows($ritem1) > 0){
            $qitem2 = "SELECT * FROM data_sum WHERE item2='".$add['item2']."'";
            $ritem2 = mysql_query($qitem2);
            if (mysql_num_rows($ritem2) > 0){
                $sql = "UPDATE Tally=Tally + 1 WHERE item1='".$add['item1']."' AND item2='".$add['item2']."'";
                $update = mysql_query($sql);
            }
            else{
                $sql = "INSERT INTO data_sum (item1, item2) VALUES('$item1', '$item2')";
                $insert = mysql_query($sql);
            }
        else{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO data_sum (item1, item2) VALUES('$item1', '$item2')";
            $insert = mysql_query($sql);
        }
```

Yes, I know the total tallies are one more than the rows in the first table. I want the rows with a null column to count towards both tallies with a common factor. This file is going to go through thousands of rows so I want utmost efficiency! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something? Anything? Anything at all?

Comment: Yes I have, but it's very lengthy. I'm trying to shorten it down for your thought right now.

Answer (score 1):

All you would need to do is create a new table and then combine an `INSERT` statement with a `GROUP BY`'d `SELECT` statement. This would `COUNT()` the number of times `item1` and `item2` were the same and store them in the new tally'd table.

Something along the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO new_tally_table (item1, item2, Tally)
SELECT item1, item2, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY item1, item2
```

Edit:
Actually re-read the last bit of your question. Think what you want is something like this:

```
SELECT item1, item2, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT i1.item1, i2.item2
    FROM table1 as i1
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT item1, item2
      FROM table1 WHERE item2 IS NOT NULL
    ) as i2 ON (i1.item1 = i2.item1)
    WHERE i1.item2 IS NULL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT item1, item2
    FROM table1
    WHERE item2 IS NOT NULL
) as t
GROUP BY item1, item2
```

There's probably a better way of writing that though.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simpler solution, but I can't think of it...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,item1  INT NULL
,item2 INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (item1,item2) VALUES
(1     ,NULL),
(1     ,2),
(1     ,3),
(1     ,3),
(2     ,3);

SELECT x.item1
     , x.item2
     , COUNT(DISTINCT y.id) 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.item1 = x.item1 
   AND (y.item2 = x.item2 OR y.item2 IS NULL)
   AND y.id <= x.id 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT item1
            , item2
            , MAX(id) max_id 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY item1
            , item2
     ) z 
    ON z.item1 = x.item1 
   AND z.item2 = x.item2 
   AND z.max_id = x.id 
 WHERE x.item2 <> 0 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id;
+-------+-------+----------------------+
| item1 | item2 | COUNT(DISTINCT y.id) |
+-------+-------+----------------------+
|     1 |     2 |                    2 |
|     1 |     3 |                    3 |
|     2 |     3 |                    1 |
+-------+-------+----------------------+
```